# Visual Studio 2017 - Force file encoding on every file opened

Tags: character-encoding, visual-studio-2017, ide

I have a project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with PHP Tools installed. Every project file has `ISO-8859-2` encoding (codepage `28592` in VS terminology), and everything works well until I try to open any file. VS wrongfully guesses the encoding as `Windows-1250` with no visible way to override this project-wide. This leads to national diacritics being loaded wrongfully and requires reopening every file with encoding manually specified.

Any ideas (other than manually specifying encoding every file opening) how to force the encoding to `ISO-8859-2` per every opened file in this project - without manual intervention?

*(To reduce any concerns why this particular encoding is used: the program **has to** comply with the national norm PN-T-42118, specifying this encoding as mandatory. This norm must be complied with at all times in the whole project - a design requirement.)*

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017 it is typically controlled by an [EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options) file with the **charset** property.

Comment: For my experience it does not work when you open the program as **folder view** (as opposed to **project/solution view** - i.e. PHP/HHVM programs does not use VS projects for anything meaningful).